# Google Update Created Bug - This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked

Tags: php, symfony, google-chrome, referrer-policy

Google Chrome started blocking downloads served via HTTP.

This update broke my download links and shows the console error below.

> Mixed Content: The site at 'https://www.sellmyiphonemiami.com/' was
> loaded over a secure connection, but the file at
> 'https://www.sellmyiphonemiami.com/order/print-shipping-label/731' was
> redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served
> over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See
> https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html
> for more details.

My pdf downloads are served over HTTPS but I still get this error.

Network console show 2 records:
First one -

> Request URL:
> http://www.sellmyiphonemiami.com/order/print-shipping-label/732
> Request Method: GET Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk
> cache) Remote Address: 52.10.157.2:80 Referrer Policy:
> strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Second one -

> Request URL:
> https://www.sellmyiphonemiami.com/order/print-shipping-label/732
> Request Method: GET Status Code: 200  Remote Address:
> 52.43.218.108:443 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Heres is my controller:

```
$filename = sprintf('FedExShippingLable-%s.pdf', $o->getTrackingNumber());
    $fs = new Filesystem();
    $fs->dumpFile($filename, $o->getDocument());
    // Generate response
    $response = new Response();
    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));
    // Send headers before outputting anything
    $response->sendHeaders();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
    $fs->remove($filename);
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was simple but I still don't understand why.

We used the twig extension 'url' which created an http request 'url' instead of https.

Changing the extension to 'path' fixed the problem.

I will not mark this as the answer because hopefully, someone can explain why the 'url' extension returned this URL 'http://www.sellmyiphonemiami.com/order/print-shipping-label/732' and why 'path' worked.

This worked:

```
 href="{{ path('label', {"id": order.id}) }}
```

This stopped working:

```
 href="{{ url('label', {"id": order.id}) }}
```

Comment: Can you link the `twig` extension in question?

Comment: @esqew I added it to answer.